# Laravel/Eloquent Paginate returning empty collection when filtering on primary key

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm working on creating a search form for customers that allows multiple options, including the customer's id (primary key).

`$res = new \App\Customer;`

When filtering on a column that isn't the primary key, everything works fine:

```
>>> $res = \App\Customer::where('customer_name', 'like', "%frank%")->first();
=> App\Customer {#736}
>>> $res = \App\Customer::where('customer_name', 'like', "%frank%")->paginate(15)->first();
=> App\Customer {#749}
```

However, filtering on the primary key and then calling `paginate()` returns an empty collection.

```
>>> $res = \App\Customer::where('id', 3)->first();
=> App\Customer {#669}
>>> $res = \App\Customer::where('id', 3)->paginate(15)->first();
=> null
```

`simplePaginate()` works fine, however I'd like to use the additional features from the full `paginate()`.

*(Yes, I understand I will only get a single record when filtering on the primary key however without calling `paginate()` on the set my view would break as it uses the pagination methods such as `firstItem()`, `lastItem()`, `total()`, etc.)*

Comment: I've just tried this on v5.3.4 and had no problems. Are you sure you're not doing anything else?

Comment: Nothing else, the above output is straight from tinker. I've even created a new project with nothing but the empty model and get the exact same output. Was on v5.3.2, just updated to v5.3.4 - same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> > > `$res = \App\Customer::where('id', 3)->paginate(15);`

Comment: This is identical to my code above. I've just added the ->first() to pull the first record returned for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why it worked, but moving my where into a scope method on the Model fixed the issue.